# Check char at current/given position in c

Tags: c, char, character, console-application, ncurses

Is there a way to check which char is at a given position in the console window? For example if I want to check if there's an asterisk (*) at position (10, 12), how do I do that? Or if I use `move(10, 12);`, how do I check which char is at the current cursor position? I'm using c.

Comment: It's OS/Platform specific. Which OS/Platform are you using ? Edit your question and make that clear.

Comment: Portably, no. There may be platfrom-specific solutions however, using e.g. ncurses or Windows APIs.